# Unable to pair Bose qc35 with Ubuntu 16.04 via bluetooth

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, headset, headphones, pairing

I am trying to pair my new Bose qc35 with my Ubuntu 16.04 machine via bluetooth. I tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833322/pair-bose-quietcomfort-35-with-ubuntu-over-bluetooth) but it did not work.

When i go into bluetoothctl i can find the headphones, but when i try and pair i get the following error:

```
    [bluetooth]# pair 04:52:C7:C5:2A:71
        Attempting to pair with 04:52:C7:C5:2A:71
        [CHG] Device 04:52:C7:C5:2A:71 Connected: yes
        Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationFailed
        [CHG] Device 04:52:C7:C5:2A:71 Connected: no
```

I have followed the advice in the above answer and set the bluetooth service to use bredr.

I tired trusting the device first and then pairing, but there is the same problem:

```
    [bluetooth]# trust 04:52:C7:C5:2A:71
        [CHG] Device 04:52:C7:C5:2A:71 Trusted: yes
        Changing 04:52:C7:C5:2A:71 trust succeeded
    [bluetooth]# pair 04:52:C7:C5:2A:71
        Attempting to pair with 04:52:C7:C5:2A:71
        [CHG] Device 04:52:C7:C5:2A:71 Connected: yes
        Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationFailed
        [CHG] Device 04:52:C7:C5:2A:71 Connected: no
```

HELP :(

Answer (score 1):

So after removing and reinstalling, it turns out that there is a connect stage. It still takes a while, but the answer was as follows:

```
connect 04:52:C7:C5:2A:71
```

Comment: The problem was that the automatic discovery process failed during the connection stage, and the connect command had to be manually retried one or more times.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by installing blueman

```
sudo apt install blueman
```

Then in bluetooth manager right click on the headphone Bose QC35 and select "pair"

Answer (score 0):

Install Blueman via following cmd:

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

Go to Bluetooth Manager open **Settings** & choose **Handsfree** option.

Then open sound settings choose the headphones as output (choose Mode as **High Fidelity Playback A2DP Sink**).

The same works for Bose Soundlink headphones too.